# Lemma2.1 (in dimension 1)in the book of Morse theory by Milnor

Tags: morse-theory

i have this lemma :

> Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function in a convex neighborhood $V$  of
>   $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ , with $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)= x g(x)$. for suitable
>   $C^\infty$ function $g$ defined in $V$ with $g(0)=f'(0)$

to prove this they say that :

$\displaystyle f(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{df(tx)}{dt} dt=\int_0^1 x \frac{df(tx)}{dx} dt...*$

Therefore we can let $\displaystyle g(x)=\int_0^1\frac{df(tx)}{dx} dt$

I don't understand why $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{df(tx)}{dt} dt=\int_0^1 x \frac{df(tx)}{dx} dt$

Please

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my copy of Milnor, you have the notation written incorrectly

All he has done there is a basic application of chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t x_1, t x_2, ..., t x_n) = f_1 (t x_1, t x_2, ..., t x_n) x_1 + f_2 (t x_1, t x_2, ..., t x_n) x_2 + \dots + f_n (t x_1, tx_2, ..., t x_n) x_n$$

where $f_i$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i^{th}$ variable.

Let's look at the scenario when $f(x) = \sin x$.  Then 
$$f(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{d f(tx)}{dt} dt = \int_0^1 x \cos(tx) dt $$

Now if we were to change the integrand to $ x \frac{d \sin(tx)}{dx}$, we'd have $x t \cos(tx)$ inside the integral.  What is meant however is $\left. x \frac{d \sin(u)}{du}\right|_{u = tx}$ which is $x \cos(tx)$ which is what you want inside the integral.

Comment: i writ it on dimension 1 ,

Comment: I see that, I mean you used the notation $\frac{f'(xt)}{dt}$ which will only end up making you more confused.  The whole expression has a time derivative and each componenent has a partial derivative, these are the only two things you need.  Milnor only ever says $\frac{ d f(xt)}{dt}$, never $\frac{f'(xt)}{dt}$ which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: i edited my question, can you see if it's just ? please

Comment: If i understand  : $\frac{d}{dt}f(tx)=\frac{df(tx)}{d(tx)}\frac{d(tx)}{dt}=x \frac{df(tx)}{d(tx)}$ ,but 
but what should I do to $d(tx)$ ?

Comment: $\frac{d f(tx)}{d (tx)}$ is just $\frac{df}{du} |_{u = tx}$.  Ie) Take the derivative with respect to a dummy variable in there.  It's asking for the partial derivative with respect to the parameter of the function, not the variables $x$ or $t$.

Comment: But we must find $df(tx)/dx$ !

Comment: This is where you are getting confused, we're never differentiating with respect to the $x$ variable, Milnor only ever means he's differentiating with respect to the parameter.  When he says $\frac{df}{dx_i}$, he means differentiate $f$ with respect to the $i^{th}$ parameter.

Comment: >_< i don't understand !

Comment: I'll put an example to explain the difference in my answer.

Comment: Ok , thank you i'm waiting ^_^

Comment: please if i put u=tx , i obtain $\frac{df(tx)}{dt}=x f'(u)$, i want to understand why they write $\frac{df(tx)}{dx}$ this i don't understand it

Comment: or it's just a writing , so i must write in dimension 1 only $x f'(tx) $ right ?

Comment: Yes in dimension $1$, it is correct to write $x f'(tx)$, this is precisely the meaning that is meant.  This is pure notational confusion you are experiencing.  Think about what we mean by $\frac{dL}{d\dot{q}}$ in classical mechanics.  It means a pure derivative with respect to the second argument of the Lagrangian.  In the same vain, $\frac{d f(xt)}{dx}$ here means $f'(xt)$ and not $\frac{d}{dx} f(xt)$

Comment: ok ,thank you for all